# Related products are not completely displayed

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

**Magento-Data:**
Magento 1.4.2 Community Edition

**What's the problem?**
When adding related products to single products they are not displayed completely or even not.
The problem occurs at the moment on five products, each of that products has between 15 and 36 related products.

Three of the affected products are showing 1 related product, the other 2 products show nothing.

**What we've tried so far:**
 - We completely rebuilt all indexes (it's done every night by cron)
 - Emtpying the cache
 - We controlled the affected single products if they:

- are in stock
- have a qty >0
- are assigned to a category and a website
- are enabled
- have a visibility of "catalog, search"

-We also checked that for every single added related product

The strange thing is, that it only occurs at a few products, all other products show their related products without problems.

I hope someone can help us with that issue and give a hint.

Best regards
tireniets

**UPDATE & SOLUTION (2016-08-04):**
The problem was caused by group products-all affected products are part of a group product. And that group product overwrites all assigned related products of its child products.

So it was no error or bug, it was just the default behavior of the group product. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Hello @Enigmativity, that's right, i accidently posted the question here. I'll copy it and post it at the magento-related stackexchange-site. So the question can be deleted/ closed.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE & SOLUTION (2016-08-04):
The problem was caused by group products-all affected products are part of a group product. And that group product overwrites all assigned related products of its child products.

So it was no error or bug, it was just the default behavior of the group product. :)